# I'm failing to see why this JS/JQuery IF statement isnt working as i'm expecting it to

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please be a little sympathetic as I'm very new to these languages.
http://jsfiddle.net/3vyJR/

what i'm trying to achieve is quite simple.
I'm trying to get the value of Jquerys scrollTop method and store it in a variable.
Then use a JS IF statement to check the value of the variable, If its less than 4 then make background green, else make it blue.

in the code below, I'm using alert to tell me the value of scrolltop when the page is loaded, and it tells me that it is 0, So I'm expecting the page to be green, but it isn't, its blue.

Can somebody tell me whats wrong with the code?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var n = $(document).scrollTop;
    alert($(document).scrollTop());
    if (n <= 4) {
        $("body").css("background", "green");
    } 
    else {
        $("body").css("background", "blue");            
    }
 });
```

Comment: `$("body").css("background", $(document).scrollTop() <= 4 ? "green" : "blue");`

Comment: @MianKhurramIjaz Incorrect. They're not calling `scrollTop()`, they're just storing a reference to the function in `n`. If they'd done `alert(n)` instead like they should have the issue would have been more obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with

```
var n = $(document).scrollTop();
```

Answer (score 3):

n is not being set as a number because you're missing the () after scrollTop;

Try:

```
var n = $(document).scrollTop();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
var n = $(document).scrollTop();
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to write

```
var n = $(document).scrollTop();
```

instead of

```
var n = $(document).scrollTop;
```

`$(document).scrollTop` returns a `function` that is implementation of `$.scrollTop()`

A typo may be?

Answer (score 1):

You have typo error to make correct you must use

var n = $(document).scrollTop();

you can use for an older doctype in IE

```
var n = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) || 
          document.body.scrollTop;
```

to get n = 0